# Can I use Magento2 back-end if we remove the domain?

Tags: magento2, orders, migration, domain

We change webshop from Magento2 to a new platform next week and would like to know if you can log into Magento after moving the domain. Do we still have acces to the backend and our orders?
Hope anyone can help with a yes or a no. :-)

Thanks!
Monica

Answer (score 3):

Could be either yes or no. Is the old domain being dropped?  If so you need to speak to whoever is in charge of the migration.  Ideally you want to go from this

`www.olddomain.com/`

`www.olddomain.com/oldadminpanel`

To this

`www.newdomain.com/`

`www.newdomain.com/newadminpanel`

With a subdomain

`archive.newdomain.com/`

`archive.newdomain.com/oldadminpanel`

Then you can get to your old data via archive.newdomain.com/oldadminpanel

This is the most cost effective solution for most.  Also that way you are asking that the old site is maintained in terms of data and files.  Otherwise you might lose something.

If the old domain isn't being dropped access will be maintained for as long as you continue to pay for hosting for old domain.

Comment: Ok - Thanks a lot :-)

Comment: @Monica No problem. If you feel this question has been answered please mark as accepted.

Answer (score 3):

access your backend by IP address:

```
php bin/magento setup:store-config:set --base-url="http://1.2.3.4/"

php bin/magento setup:store-config:set --use-secure=0

php bin/magento cache:flush
```

where 1.2.3.4 is your old IP address. that simple.

```
http://1.2.3.4/admin_xxxx
```